Is there good and bad philosophy?
There appear to be a number of positions differentiating between legitimate and illegitimate methodologies of knowledge and schools of thought, but they sometimes seem to exhibit an artificial true-by-definition characteristic. Observing the different viewpoints on what philosophy is, whether or not philosophy is valuable or useful, and if so which aspects, and why, could be an interesting topic to study in the sociology of science, regarding what people in society think science and philosophy are and what their implicit epistemological standpoint is.
I can think of some examples of a school of thought contrasting itself with “those bad epistemologists”, so to speak: those whose method of knowledge is purportedly wrong.
Ancient philosophers decried the Sophists, who used rhetoric instead of sound analysis to make claims about the world.
Logical positivists seemingly rejected anything that is not “strictly logical”.
Analytic philosophers have often rejected continental philosophers, on the grounds that continental philosophy lacks precision, whereas analytic philosophy is almost the avant-guard of natural science: people like Chomsky tried to move the study of the mind from a kind of rationalist Cartesian inquiry to a theory of such definiteness that it became an empirical science. Similarly, Albert Einstein said that theorists are “tamed metaphysicians” who try to deduce the nature of the world almost through pure thought alone.
Quine had his own views on epistemology, and used the word “science” in a much broader way than the conventional idea of “the scientific method”.
In contemporary times, there is a school of thought termed “scientism”, which stresses the value of science to the total exclusion of philosophy. But this perspective seems to assume that philosophy is by definition something without theoretical productiveness.
It is also said that up until the 19th century, science and philosophy were not particularly separated branches of knowledge; what we now call scientists were called “natural philosophers”.
Thus, there is kind of a chain of finger-pointing where one epistemological camp points its finger at another as the exemplar of bad epistemology, while some other camp is pointing the finger at them.
Has anyone studied the sociology of epistemology from this point of view, before?

I receny made this list which is analogous to your list of disputations. Beyond that I'm unable what you're asking

Surely it is trivial to invent a "bad epistemology" to serve as an example?  The "because I said so" epistemology, in which things are true iff I said so.  The "buffalo buffalo buffalo" epistemology in which a statement is true iff it can be expressed entirely using only the word "buffalo".  There are an infinite number of equally and even more ridiculous epistemologies awaiting your imagination.

Good and bad epistemology?
If you want to compare epistemologies and judge some as "better" than others, you'd need criteria to evaluate them with.
The best criteria I can imagine is that of reliability: when an epistemology judges something as true or false, how often is that correct.
Reliability (reliabilism) is itself an epistemology, and this may in a sense be saying reliabilism is "better" than other epistemologies or meta-epistemologies.
But the merits of reliability is self-evident: it is, by definition, what is correct most often. If you care about believing as many true things and as few false things as possible, that is reliabilism. If you want the outcomes of your actions to match your intent, having the most accurate model of reality would be crucial for predicting the outcomes of your actions, and that's what reliabilism selects for.
If we want to measure the reliability of epistemology (especially as it relates to metaphysics), we need to be careful to avoid circularity, since epistemology is what we use for determining what's true.
But there are still some potentially useful ways we can measure reliability in this regard:

See whether an epistemology produces contradictions (or mutually-exclusive outcomes) when used by the same person, or contradictions between different people (e.g. my intuition tells me X, your intuition tells you not-X).
Contradictions provide an upper limit on reliability (supposing the law of non-contradiction, and that we live in a shared reality). If many people all use the same epistemology to evaluate a particular claim, and only 50% end up with the same conclusion, we can say the reliability is somewhere between 0% and 50%. If the 50% is right, you have 50% reliability. If they're wrong, it may be less. It can't be more than 50%.

The accuracy of predictions could be argued is a measure of reliability (supposing reality behaves consistently). Correct predictions indicates that our models of the behaviour of reality is accurate.
Of course we can only know if a prediction is accurate after the fact. This relates to the problem of induction, i.e. being able to justify predictions about unobserved things based on previous observations. One might say that the simplest explanation for the evidence is that the universe behaves in consistent ways that enables us to draw such inferences. We can trust future predictions (that follow a robust process) because many such predictions turned out to be correct, and we've gotten better and better at figuring out how to make more and more accurate predictions. All of science is built on that idea, and one would have a hard time explaining why any modern technology works if induction isn't a fact.
As it relates to reliability:

Let's say we have a specific truth claim, e.g. this medicine cures this disease. We can make some predictions based on that, e.g. if we give the medicine to some people who have the disease and not others, the ones who got the medicine will recover from the disease more than those who didn't get the medicine. We can then perform that experiment, and see if those predictions were correct. If they were, we might lean towards accepting the original claim: this medicine cures this disease.

For epistemology more broadly, we can review the above process and see whether it leads to correct predictions after our initial experiment. And indeed, scientists have done this a lot. We've figured out that experiments with more samples makes for more accurate predictions than ones with fewer samples - we've boiled that down to concrete mathematical formulas. We've figured out that there often are confounding variables that we need to look out for, which is the whole reason we run separate controlled experiments where we make predictions, rather than just drawing conclusions from past data. Etc. In this way, we've refined our process to be more and more accurate and reliable.


Although accurate predictions doesn't say much about the fundamental nature of reality, but one might argue that this is something we can't know in any case. The best we can do is model behaviour.

See if an epistemology produces a coherent worldview. This also relates to correct predictions and non-contradictions. Coherentism is criticised for allowing arbitrary beliefs, but if we approach it through the lens of reliable epistemology, you'd need to follow some non-arbitrary method to conclude the truth of anything and everything in that worldview. And you shouldn't be able to follow that method, or a comparable method, to conclude the truth of anything inconsistent or contradictory with claims in that worldview. This puts some rather significant limits on what worldviews can be proposed, favouring ones that are less arbitrary.



The challenge for other epistemologies, and proposed criteria for evaluating epistemologies, would be to similarly justify the value in what they're proposing - why should we use that above this?
Good and bad philosophy?
Judging philosophies as good or bad might be more difficult.
The most basic criteria I can imagine would be that you can justify or explain why you hold that particular position (and do so without fallacies).
This might eventually boil down to Münchhausen trilemma of the apparent impossibility of any absolute deductive proof, but that doesn't mean all positions are equally justified.
Beyond that, it might be more of a subjective judgement to determine which philosophies are "good" and which are "bad" (and which are "useful" and which are "a complete waste of time", if any).
Scientism?

"scientism", which stresses the value of science to the total exclusion of philosophy

This is not an accurate representation of scientism.
You yourself allude to the issue with your claim by acknowledging that science wasn't separate from philosophy in the past. Science came from philosophy, and is justified through that, and scientism is a philosophical position that's evaluated other epistemologies and found them to be lacking.
More often than not, "scientism" is used dismissively, as an "ism-ification" (add "ism" to a thing, to make people think it's bad), rather than as a term people use to describe themselves. I myself tend not to adopt that label, but prefer something like reliabilism, since that emphasises why we should value science: because it's a reliable method. And it's harder for people to accuse me of having dogmatic adherence to science - any reliable method would be accepted. The fact that no other reliable methods have been produced is exactly the issue. One can argue about how maths and logic fits into this, but people who value science tend to already accept those to the extent that they're reliable.
At best, I might agree that there are some people who value science and dismiss modern philosophy, without fully knowing or appreciating science's philosophical roots and the philosophical justification for their position. But there are also those who argue for science and against much of modern philosophy by using and engaging philosophical arguments. And even plenty of people dismissive of "philosophy" do still make arguments that could reasonably be labelled as philosophy. One might say this is because the common perception of philosophy tends to be that of metaphysics and ontology and such: a lot of obscure and intricate arguments that seem entirely divorced from reality, and that fails to produce of value. I am quite critical of much of metaphysics discussion, but that certainly isn't all philosophy is.

Somewhat just to counter that idea, but actually "reliabilitism" is much worse than scientism. The thing is a lot of things are reliable until they aren't so if your model of the world is build on pure inductive reasoning (it works because it worked), then no argument but the failure of that model is going to convince you of it's problems, which depending on how serious that failure is, can make a dogmatic adherence to this idea very dangerous. While the reduction that science often aims for at least allows for experiments and toy examples where failure is welcomed and contained.

Also don't get me wrong, I see the concept that science essentially takes reality itself as ruler, so whether it's good or bad science comes down to whether it actually works or doesn't and thus could be described by it's reliability, though any sort of -ism somewhat builds an understanding of the world around an action or idea, which has a really hard time to avoid dogma as it essentially starts from one.

@haxor789 Using something that works may be a problem if it stops working? Then it would no longer be reliable! So continuing to use it wouldn't be consistent with reliabilism. Also, your argument seems to suggest we should use things that already failed because things which haven't failed might fail at some point in future, which doesn't make much sense. Reliabilism is about using the most reliable thing (or things). This doesn't preclude you from taking precautions to mitigate risks. Also, I don't know about "a lot of things" going from reliable to unreliable, within epistemology.

The problem is that "reliability" is a deceiving concept. Because it is "the trust in the predictability of future events". But how reliable those predictions actually are, can only be determined in hindsight. So you can only really assume reliability by how well something worked on past data, however there's always also an infinite amount of nonsense theories that also explain past data and would only be able to be falsified by ... well failure. For example overfitting aka perfect retroprediction abysmal forward prediction. So that's important, but that's not all that matters, is it?

@haxor789 That is entirely incorrect. The reliability in science is heavily based in predictions, and that's definitely not just in hindsight. Correct predictions are needed to validate a theory BEFORE we treat it as reliable. We don't put medicine on the shelf based on retrofitted data - you need a positive result from a study specifically testing that. If you retrofit a model that fits past data perfectly but has abysmal predictions, it will most likely fail the prediction test and won't be classified as reliable. The problem of "overfitting" is already extensively accounted for here.

@haxor789 Also, your argument can be paraphrased as: it is not a reliable method to trust models based purely on retrofitting past data. Your argument is itself invoking reliability to argue seeming-but-not-actual reliability. So it's really just an argument that we should take care in how we're measuring reliability (which of course we should and do) - it's not a counter-argument against reliability.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There is certainly bad philosophy, where people's arguments are unsupported, or a premise is counterfactual or provisional without being noted as such. Philosophy is potentially subject to the whole constellation of possible logic errors, cognitive biases, and so on. That also gives us a basis for a scale of relative quality.
Note that I am interpreting bad as "poorly executed and/or unsuccessful." If you want to know whether there is such a thing as evil philosophy, that gets into the philosophical discussion of how you define evil.

My own bete noire is folks who conveniently forget that words have multiple meanings.

+1 Very Nietzschean...

@Philomath: Not having read Nietzsche, I'm going to hope I can take that as a compliment.  (I've admitted I am still a philosophical ignoramus...)

Nietzsche wrote in his Genealogy about two pairs of opposites: 'good vs bad' and 'good vs evil'. The first relates to an aristocratic (later the Ueberrmensch) view of good and bad. Just like you did with regard to quality / success. The latter pair relates to the slave morality, which inverted the earlier good to an evil out of resentment. The two 'goods' have different meanings. You referred to that in your comment. So, yeah, a compliment though Nietzsche is far from the be all and all of philosophy. Sorry if I can't explain Nietzsche in a comment. That would require more space...


Is there good and bad philosophy?

Certainly most philosophers think so, but in the spirit of philosophy, they seldom agree. Rene Descartes had very specific views on philosophy, and Rudolf Carnap had very specific views on philosophy, and so to did Willard Quine. And quine is famous for arguing that we naturalize philosophy. But ultimately what constitutes good or bad epistemology, ontology, or philosophy is found in various literatures generally characterized with the meta- prefix. One example is the meta-ethical view of non-cognitive emotivism. Another "meta term" is metaphilosophy which studies and tries to make sense of the various arguments philosophers assert about the nature of philosophy. As for the sociology of epistemology, a good source (as per the usual) is PhilPapers.org (search for sociology of epistemology).

One book makes an excellent review of these questions: An Essay on
Metaphysics by RG Collingwood.
